# Ctrl+x cut operation Doesn't works on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I  have bound a `DataTable` with the `DataGridView` as in the below image.

[image: DataGridView]

I need to select multiple cells and perform a cut operation by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> on the keyboard, but I can't get this to work.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to code the whole thing. See [here for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+datagridview+clipboard)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send to clipboard datagridview content like CTRL-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090196/how-to-send-to-clipboard-datagridview-content-like-ctrl-c)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do when your application receives a "cut" (cntrl-X) command is to copy the selected cells to the clipboard.  You then need to remove those cells from the datagrid pragmatically by first updating your database (delete/remove the 'cut' data), and then refreshing your datagridview to reflect the change.

Note: it is up to your design if you want to wait to actually commit the data change until the data is no longer in the clipboard because if you make all the changes permanent, it will be harder to perform a potential 'undo'.

To copy the selected cells your code should look something like this:

```
private void CopyPasteButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataGridView1
        .GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
{
    try
    {
        // Add the selection to the clipboard.
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(
            this.DataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());

        // Replace the text box contents with the clipboard text.
        this.TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
    {
        this.TextBox1.Text = 
            "The Clipboard could not be accessed. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

I see a potential problem that you may need to address.  In your picture you are only selecting some of the columns of your data grid view.  If this view represents an entire database table, you may want the user to select an entire row instead of a partial row.

Comment: but how this code remove the values from the cells??

Comment: from DataGridViewElementStates.Selected, you know which cells should be removed.  Before you committ changes to your DB you may just want to remove those rows from your GridView, You can do a refresh the view and block the adding of those selected rows.  Note my comment that you should only have the user select a whole row and not a partial one.